# AS3 Keep Image aspect ratio

Tags: image, actionscript-3

I am trying to resize peoples Facebook images for use in a flash application, the problem is the application takes the image from its original form down to a 68px - 68px square which spoils the ratio.

Is there any way of fixing this?

*Code:*

```
var ImgWidth:Number = 68;
var ImgHeight:Number = 68;

fb_profile_img.width = ImgWidth;
fb_profile_img.height = ImgHeight;
MovieClipName[InstanceName].addChild(fb_profile_img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ImgWidth:Number = 68;
var ImgHeight:Number = 68;

var k:Number = ImgHeight / ImgWidth;
if( fb_profile_img.width * k > fb_profile_img.height ){
    k = ImgWidth / fb_profile_img.width;
}else{
    k = ImgHeight / fb_profile_img.height;
}
fb_profile_img.width *= k;
fb_profile_img.height *= k;
MovieClipName[InstanceName].addChild(fb_profile_img);
```